# Odd behavior of now() and db\Expression in yii2/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I can't make the following code behave like it should (deleting expired records). Simple test code:

test_expire table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_expire` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `expire` timestamp NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Code:

```
TestExpire::deleteAll();

$record = new TestExpire();
$record->expire = new Expression("NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH");
$record->save();

$record = new TestExpire();
$record->expire = new Expression("NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR");
$record->save();

$records = TestExpire::find('expire > :expire', ['expire' => date('Y-m-d')])->all();
echo "Records (" . count($records) . "):\n";
foreach($records as $record) {
    echo "Expire: " . $record->expire . "\n";
}
TestExpire::deleteAll("expire < NOW()");
$records = TestExpire::find('expire > :expire', ['expire' => date('Y-m-d')])->all();
echo "Records after delete 1: " . count($records) . "\n";

TestExpire::deleteAll("expire < :expire", [':expire' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s')]);
$records = TestExpire::find('expire > :expire', ['expire' => date('Y-m-d')])->all();
echo "Records after delete 2: " . count($records) . "\n";

TestExpire::deleteAll("expire < :expire", [':expire' => new Expression("NOW()")]);
$records = TestExpire::find('expire > :expire', ['expire' => date('Y-m-d')])->all();
echo "Records after delete 3: " . count($records) . "\n";
```

Well I expect all deleteAll expressions be the same, each of them not deleting records. But the last one does. Here's the output:

```
Records (2):
Expire: 2015-01-05 14:52:02
Expire: 2015-12-05 14:52:02
Records after delete 1: 2
Records after delete 2: 2
Records after delete 3: 0
```

The question is why it happens and how to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the last sql query is :

```
DELETE FROM `test_expire` WHERE expire < 'NOW()';
```

Instead of

```
DELETE FROM `test_expire` WHERE expire < NOW();
```

Thanks for reporting this bug, I created an issue here : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6382

**EDIT** : As explained on Yii issue tracker, parameter binding is a pdo feature, don't use it with db expressions.